# Spring lazy initialization applies to imported configuration classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I enable `spring.main.lazy-initialization=true` then Spring does not instantiate configuration classes referenced by `@Import`.

I have to explicitly `@Autowire` them into entrypoint to get them picked up. At least in tests.

Is this expected?

It's problematic for me because this will ignore registration of handlers such as `@KafkaListener`.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little confusing. You enabled lazy initialization, and then are surprised when a bean isn't initialized unless you use it. But that is exactly what [lazy initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) is.

Consider using the [`@Lazy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) annotation to have more fine-grained control over what is and isn't lazy initialized.

If you want to continue using `spring.main.lazy-initialization=true`, try adding `@Lazy(false)` to your Kafka listeners.

Otherwise, remove the property and add `@Lazy` only to the beans which you really want to be lazy.

Comment: I use `lazy-initialization=true` to speed up tests. Unfortunately annotating everything I want or don't want with @Lazy is too annoying whichever way I go. I guess I would like to control laziness at the level of configuration import. Global property is too broad while per-component is too fine grained.

Comment: You can add `@Lazy` to a `@Configuration` class.